# Why is this simple reindex Panda df function not working?

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

I'm trying to reindex dataframes within a function but it's not working.  It works outside of the function so I'm totally lost.  Here's what I'm doing:

Reindexing df2 based on index from df1

Outside of function:

```py
df2 = df2.reindex(df1.index)
```

This result is what I want ,and works.  However, within this function:

```
def reindex_df(a,b):
    a = a.reindex(b.index)
```

where `a = df2` and `b = df1`.

What's going on here? I've researched and thought something to do with local vs. global variables, but tweaked code (to this) and still not working.  What am I missing????

Comment: Aren't you simply missing a ``return`` statement at the end of your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare 2 following examples:

1. A function **substituting** a new value under a parameter:

   ```
   def f1(a):
       a = a + 1

   a = 10
   print(f'Before: {a}')
   f1(a)
   print(f'After:  {a}')
   ```

   The result is:

   ```
   Before: 10
   After:  10
   ```

   so that the substitution in *f1* is **not** visible outside this function.
2. A function **returning** the new value:

   ```
   def f2(a):
       return a + 1

   a = 10
   print(f'Before: {a}')
   a = f2(a)
   print(f'After:  {a}')
   ```

   This time the result is:

   ```
   Before: 10
   After:  11
   ```

So change your function the same way. It should **return** the new
(reindexed) DataFrame and when you call it, substitute the result
under the same variable.